# How to export a dataset with "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" as a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, spatialdataframe

How to export spatial datasets in R, such as `tornados` dataset in `GISTools` package, as a shapefile with the exact same spatial reference and the exact values?

```r
library(GISTools)

data(tornados)
```

Desired:

- "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" to "shapefile"
- "(Forced) SpatialPointsDataFrame" to "shapefile"
- "(Non-Forced) SpatialPointsDataFrame" to "shapefile"
- "SpatialLinesDataFrame" to "shapefile".

Comment: `rgdal::writeOGR`

Comment: What does Forced mean here?

Comment: I am not sure what "Forced" means but I found it in "GISTools" documentation under the tornado data type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wesley's answer is correct. So to specifically export the tornado data you need to do:

```
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal)
data(tornados)

writeOGR(obj=torn, dsn="tempdir", layer="torn", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in geographical projection

writeOGR(obj=torn2, dsn="tempdir", layer="torn2", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in equal area projection
```

For R both of these datasets are simply treated as SpatialPointsDataFrames.

```
> class(torn)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> class(torn2)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Answer (score 9):

Note there is also a function in the `maptools` package to accomplish this, namely `writeSpatialShape`:

```
library(maptools)
writeSpatialShape(torn, "torn").
```

See [`?writeSpatialShape`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maptools/versions/0.9-4/topics/readShapeSpatial) for options.

Comment: This function does not retain the proj4string information.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans: so is there a way to pass that? perhaps reassign it in the GIS package it's going to.

Comment: @val just use `writeOGR`

Comment: @MichaelChirico: thx but thats where I began and the issue is that it truncates to an Error... duplicate fields. There are posts about it.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at the [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package, specifically the `writeOGR` function.

For example, I first downloaded the 110m-resolution "States and Provinces" shapefiles from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/), unpacking them to `~/scratch/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces`. I read them into R via:

```
library(rgdal)
setwd("~/scratch")
states <- readOGR(dsn="ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces",
    layer="ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces")
```

At this point, the object `states` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Now I create a new directory ("`tempdir`") and save the shapefiles there:

```
dir.create("tempdir")
writeOGR(obj=states, dsn="tempdir", layer="states", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

The shapes are now saved to the directory `~/scratch/tempdir`, as files states.shp, etc. You can do the same thing with a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, just see the first example in the documentation of the `writeOGR` function.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(raster)
shapefile(tornados, filename='path/to/file.shp')
```

Make sure you have (or have given yourself) permissions to write to the directory.