# How to convert coordinates to shapefile with R package's dataset?

Tags: shapefile, r, spdep

I need construct spatial weight matrix for data which syear=1995 (house$s1995==1)in `house`dataset in `spdep`package,So I tried `writeOGR` function as the link suggeust to get shapefile [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/how-to-export-a-dataset-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-as-a-shapefile).

The shapfile was built successfully，but when I use `readShapePoly` to read,it gets error.

There is my code:

```
library(spdep)
library(rgdal)
data(house)
house=house[which(house$s1995==1),]
class(house)
writeOGR(obj=house, dsn="test", layer="house", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: does 'test' exist in your working directory?

Comment: Yes，this will create test folder in my working directory

Comment: good. Isn't readShapePoly (maptools) now deprecated for 'rgdal::readOGR'?

Comment: I also tried rgdal::readOGR, it goes wrong with 'cannot open layer'

Comment: `readOGR("./test/house.shp")` definitely doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry,I checked my code, it works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `house` data is *POINTS* so `readShapePOLY` will fail because you are trying to read points into polygons.

This should be obvious from the error message:

```
> readShapePoly("./test/house.shp")
Error in .Map2PolyDF(Map, IDs = IDvar, proj4string = proj4string, force_ring = force_ring,  : 
  NULL geometry found: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 21
In addition: Warning message:
```

BUT you haven't shown us your code for reading or the error message, so I'm guessing here.

You can use `readShapePoints` and get a deprecation warning:

```
> h2 = readShapePoints("./test/house.shp")
Warning message:
readShapePoints is deprecated; use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read
```

Or `readOGR` from `rgdal`:

```
> h2 = rgdal::readOGR("./test/house.shp")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/SO/324090/test/house.shp", layer: "house"
with 4130 features
It has 24 fields
>
```

Comment: Thank you,it's very useful!I do try read points into polygons.So if I want to get spatial weight matrix from points,what should I do?

Comment: I found [link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1690577) says'The list of neighbours provided with the data set in spdep is a sphere of influence
graph constructed from a triangulation of the point coordinates of the houses
after projection to the Ohio North NAD83 (HARN) Lambert Conformal Conical
specification (EPSG:2834).' I tried google  'triangulation of point coordinates in r',but nothing found.

Comment: Try asking a new question rather than expecting an answer in these comments to my answer.