# R raster to shapefile

Tags: raster, shapefile, r

I created a raster with the function `rasterFromXYZ()` in R using a dataframe with coordinates and the value of a variable, the result was this:

```
plot(raster1)
```

[image]

which is exactly what I need. Now I just want to convert/export it exactly like that as a shapefile.
I guess it should be easy but I haven't found the answer... Somebody?

Comment: Check out rasterToPolygons and writeOGR: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.9-23/topics/rasterToPolygons and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/how-to-export-a-dataset-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-as-a-shapefile

Comment: If you don't specifically need a shapefile, you could also export the raster itself to a supported format via writeRaster: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.9-23/topics/writeRaster

Comment: @smiler when i use rasterToPolygons i obtain something totally different, like very smalls empty squares instead of what i have here.
and i would rather have it as a shapefile in order to work with it later on

Comment: Were there any attributes with the polygons?

Comment: @smiller, this is what i got with the polygons..  https://imgur.com/INk2dA7

Comment: Did you utilize the dissolve option, and was the raster value transferred to the attributes table of the polygons created?

Comment: I dont know what the disolve option ist ^^ , raster was created with coordinates and temperature values. The figure with the polygons is what i obtain when i give: raster2=rasterToPolygons(raster1)   
plot(raster2)

Comment: What do you want to achive - what the shapefile should look like (points, lines with levels, polygons of levels, boundaries, etc.)?

Comment: @Oto Kaláb, i dont know exactly what of those would be the right option, i just want it to look exactly like it looks in R (graph above), differentiating the scales of values with the colors with very good definition

Comment: You could check out gdalpolygonize here: https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/

Comment: @smiller i saw that before, its just an intro to rasterToPolygons but its not what im looking for i guess, already tried

Comment: So you've run through the gdal_polygonizeR.py code, what do you get? Please edit your post to include what you've tried already and what occurs when you try.

Comment: @Davido, if you are sure that you need the shapefile (vectors), than try to reclassify raster to some reasonable categories and than perform some raster to polygon function.

Answer (score 6):

Let's make a reproducible example...

First use the `raster::getData` package to get a raster of the heights of Liechtenstein (because Liechtenstein is quite small so we can see what its doing, and also because I played in a band that had a number 3 hit in the country...):

```
> library(raster)
> library(sp)
> raster1 = getData('alt', country='LIE', mask=TRUE)
> plot(raster1)
```

[image]

That's a raster like yours. Let's convert to vector format as a Spatial Data Frame. Each pixel becomes a rectangle and the altitude is stored in the `LIE_msk_alt` column:

```
> polys1 = rasterToPolygons(raster1)
> names(polys1)
[1] "LIE_msk_alt"
```

Now we can plot that using `spplot` with the same colour scheme as the `raster` plotting function:

```
> cols = rev(terrain.colors(255))
> spplot(polys1, "LIE_msk_alt", col.regions=cols, lwd=0)
```

[image]

which is near enough to the raster plot.

If you want to save this as a shapefile, then use `raster::shapefile`:

```
> raster::shapefile(polys1, "polys1.shp")
```

BUT note that shapefiles **DO NOT** save the style (the colour palette etc), only the data.

Comment: Perhaps a no-brainer, but remember to install packages (raster, sp, rgdal).